# "Unrecognized Guid Format" when attempting to assign null in conversion using Coalesce

Tags: c#

I have a method where I convert a datatable to a list.  I have no problem with all of the other nullable fields except for the Guid.  My code is as follows:

```
else if (pro.PropertyType == typeof(Guid?))
{
    pro.SetValue(obj, dr.IsNull(column.ColumnName) ? (Guid?)null : Guid.Parse(dr[column.ColumnName].ToString()), null);
}
```

I am not understanding why it will not accept the (Guid?)null.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `dr[column.ColumnName].ToString()`? The message implies this does not represent a valid guid.

Comment: "Unrecognized Guid Format" is far more likely being thrown by `Guide.Parse()` than having anything to do with null assignment.

Comment: dr[column.ColumnName].ToString()  is "".

Comment: "" looks pretty invalid to me. Are you surprised that `Guid.Parse()` fails then? Instead of checking IsNull(), check if it's an empty string. Or do it in addition to.

Comment: @itsme86 - thank you for the suggestion.  I didn't think about it until you mentioned it. It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

`""` is not a valid Guid Format

This is valid:

```
var foo = "efe02d75-ee49-44c5-afd3-72a2414576d9";
Guid guid = Guid.Parse(foo);
```

but this is not:

```
var foo = "";
Guid guid = Guid.Parse(foo);
```

nor should it be. Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.parse?view=netframework-4.8 the valid formats for `Guid.Parse()` are:

- 00000000000000000000000000000000
- 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
- {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
- (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)
- {0x00000000,0x0000,0x0000,{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}}

I think you may better have use of `Guid.TryParse()`

Answer (score 0):

Per the suggestion of @itsme86, I changed to:

```
else if (pro.PropertyType == typeof(Guid?))
{
  pro.SetValue(obj, string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr[column.ColumnName].ToString()) ? (Guid?)null : Guid.Parse(dr[column.ColumnName].ToString()), null);
}
```